# Is it possible to add watch for changes in ng build in Visual Studio Pre Build events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, build, visual-studio-2017, watch

I have an `angular-cli` based project in Visual Studio 2017. I followed the below link for this setup and it works.
http://candordeveloper.com/2017/04/12/how-to-use-angular-cli-with-visual-studio-2017/

I have the following in my Pre-Build events:

```
echo "cd $(SolutionDir)" &&^
cd "$(SolutionDir)" &&^
echo "Building Project" &&^
ng build &&^
echo 'copy files' &&^
```

This works fine when I Build or Rebuild the project in Visual Studio. It generates the bundle files in my output directory based in angular-cli.json.

But I need a way to watch for changes in `ng build` from inside Visual Studio. I tried `ng build --watch` in Pre Build events, but after making this change, my Build process stucks. I can see the output directory getting generated with all the correct bundle files, but the build process never completes in Visual Studio 2017.

As a work around, I am not running `ng build --watch` in a separate command window. This works and watch for TypeScript, HTML, CSS changes and rebuilds (as expected). But would like to integrate this inside Visual Studio 2017.

**Note**: I already have `"compileOnSave": true` in my tsconfig.json, but its not same as `ng build`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for an answer, this is what I've added to the Pre-build event in VStudio:

```
powershell start-process "cmd " """/k ng build --watch"""
```

It opens a new cmd window, starts the ng build process and keeps waiting for changes. Granted, you have to kill the cmd window once you are done with your debug session. Otherwise, it will open a new cmd window the next time you hit F5

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @santiago, now it starts a cmd window and recompiles when a change is done. Now after the recompile i need to copy the output to another directory. is there a way that i can attach another process to copy the files?

Comment: @JenonD, _'ng build'_ compiles the application into an output folder (_dist_ by default). You can change this behavior by modifying the _angular-cli.json_ file. Look for the outDir property inside apps.

Comment: @santiago, i have a angular cli project and .net mvc web project, i need to copy the newly build files (from the above powershell script) to the .net mvc project. So that i can just refresh the browser to see the changes. Calling another npm task manually or stop visual studio and rebuild is painfully slow. I am following this link http://candordeveloper.com/2017/04/12/how-to-use-angular-cli-with-visual-studio-2017/. So far it is all good, but will be perfect if i can speed up the development process with a auto file copy right after ng build.

Comment: @jenond, the above powershell just runs the _ng build_ command on a separate process so Visual Studio can continue with its own building process. The _ng build_ command is governed by the _angular-cli.json_ configuration file. You can change the _outDir_ property on that file to the folder where you want the files to be copied after each build or after a change is detected. By default, _ng build_ copies the files to the _dist_ folder, you can change it, for example, to _Scripts\NgApp_

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason it doesn't work as part of a build event in Visual Studio is that Visual Studio is waiting for the script to finish before moving on with the build process. When watching, the script never "finishes" as its constantly monitoring for changes as part of the Angular CLI build process.

Personally looking to automate this myself.

Comment: thanks for clarification on why ng build with watch cannot be hooked with visual studio.

Comment: Please, Pawan Pillai, check my answer below. Regards.